# Running nodejs as systemd service -

Tags: systemd, rhel, services, selinux, node.js

I've tried running a nodejs server on RHEL by running a .js file with node and ran into the issue of being unable to bind to **port 80**, changing to a higher port fixed this, but I was unable to access it externally leading me to assume that incoming requests were being blocked by `firewalld`. Unblocking a specific port didn't seem like an elegant solution so I looked into how to set up the nodejs server to be run as a systemd service which could be registered with `firewalld`.

I created a `webserver.service` file and a user `httpserver` as a system account to run the service, but have run into an issue after attempting to actually run it.

```bash
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start webserver
Failed to start webserver.service: Unit webserver.service not found.
```

I've seen other issues on this have potentially to do with SELinux, but I've tried `setenforce permissive` before retrying as well as trying `chcon system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0` on `webserver.service` and have had no luck.

Here are the contents of `/etc/systemd/user/webserver.service`:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=test service for server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=httpserver
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/user/ ... /index.js
Restart=on-failure


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: try moving the `webserver.service` file into `/etc/systemd/system` - not sure what `/etc/systemd/user` folder is used for, but I tried moving one of my nodejs services into there and it didn't work. Have always used `systemd/system` - see [this documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User)

Comment: @JaromandaX hey and it works! Sort of at least, the service was found. I've read through the documentation briefly and see that I've been confused on what user units and system units are used for. I was trying to use a user unit search path because `system start` required sudo and thought that running as a user unit would restrict the service's capabilities.

Comment: @grass User units must be located under `/home/your_user/.config/systemd/user/` dir. And you can *enable/disable/start/stop/restart* them by using `systemctl --user [actions] [unit]`. For example: `systemctl --user start webserver.service`

Comment: however, *User units can not reference or depend on system units or units of other users.* - from my link above - so I don't believe you can `After=network.target` or `WantedBy=multi-user.target`